# Proof of continuity

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, discrete-mathematics, continuity

Let $$f:\mathbb{R}\mapsto \mathbb{R}.$$ Prove that if f is differentiable at a real number c, then f is continuous at c.

Comment: Hi, John. Do you remember the definition of differentiability? Try using that, and tell us what you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the definition of differentiation at a point c. So you have 
$$ f'(c) = \lim_{x\rightarrow c}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}. $$ To start the problem off you can use the fact that 
$$ f(x)-f(c) = \frac{f(x)-f(c)}{(x-c)}(x-c). $$ Finally, by the definition of continuity $$\lim_{x\rightarrow c} f(x) = f(c). $$ There are a few missing steps.

Comment: Traditionally, I think $$f'(c) := \lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(c + h) - f(c)}{h}$$ which then requires a bit more work..

Comment: @BryanUrízar: same thing.

Comment: @dfeuer Of course, but you have to *prove* it's the same thing. I've always seen differentiation defined as I have in which case you have to *prove* they're equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: If $f'(c)$ exists, then the quantity $$\frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x - c}$$ is bounded in a neighborhood of $c$. If $L$ is the bound, then $|f(x) - f(c)| \le L|x - c|$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: To start, play around with $$\lim_{h\to0} f(c + h) - f(c).$$

Finally, to be fully rigorous, you will also have to show that $\lim_{h\to0} f(c + h) - f(c) = 0$ is equivalent to $\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = f(c)$ which is a simple excersise.

Answer (score 0):

given $ \varepsilon>0$, for $1>0$ with $ \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow c}\dfrac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}=f^{\prime}(c)$ there $\delta>0$ such that $0<\vert x-c\vert<\delta$ then $\vert \dfrac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}-f^{\prime}(c)\vert<1 \Rightarrow \vert f(x)-f(c)-f^{\prime}(c)(x-c)\vert< \vert x-c\vert$ $$\vert f(x)-f(c)\vert<(1 +\vert f^{\prime}(c)\vert )\vert x-c\vert$$ of which is sufficient to consider $\delta_1 <\dfrac{\varepsilon}{1 +\vert f^{\prime}(c)\vert} $.