# If $f$ is differentiable at $a$, then $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)$ exists.

Tags: calculus, analysis

I am looking at the usual proof that differentiability implies continuity (see e.g. [here](https://ximera.osu.edu/mooculus/calculus1/master/derivativeAsAFunction/digInDifferentiabilityImpliesContinuity)), which uses only the Difference and Product Rules for Limits (and in particular, doesn't use any results or ideas about sequential limits or epsilons and deltas).

This "usual proof" seems to assume that $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)$ exists. But is this obvious? Don't we need to also do a little work to show that:

> If $f$ is differentiable at $a$, then $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)$ exists.

Is the above claim somehow obvious and I'm missing something? Or is there a gap in the "usual proof"?

Comment: It's not necessary to show continuity by first showing the existence of a limiting value, etc. One may proceed directly to show that the limiting value both exists and is equal to the value of the function. This is what the usual construction does.

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/499128/42969

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $x \ne a$ we have

$$f(x)-f(a)= \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} \cdot(x-a).$$

Since $\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} \to f'(a)$ as $x \to a$,

we get that $f(x)-f(a) \to f'(a) \cdot 0=0$ as $x \to a$. This shows that $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)$ exists and that $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)=f(a).$ Hence $f$ is continuous at $a$.

Answer (score 2):

$f(x)-f(a) =(x-a)\frac {f(x)-f(a)} {x-a} \to (0)(f'(a))=0$ since limit of a product is the product of the limits. Hence $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ exists and equals $f(a)$.

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is differentiable at $a$ you can by definition write $f(x) = f(a) + f'(a) (x-a) + (x-a) \varepsilon(x)$ on a neighborhood of $a$ with $\varepsilon$ a function with limit $0$ as $x\rightarrow a$. So you see that your assertion is true.